# Find all paths from source to destination in a weighted cyclic directed graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, breadth-first-search, depth-first-search

I'm trying to find all possible paths from source to destination in a directed graph where edges have weight. There exist cycles but should not lead to infinite loops.

I have used BFS but was unable to detect cycles so that I can consider them as well in the routes.

For example I have the following adjacency list:

```
'C':['D','E']
'D':['E','C']
'E':['B']
'B':['C']
```

For source being 'C' and destination being 'C' too, assuming that paths should be no longer than 4 stops, I would have the following routes as result:

CDC
CEBC

Comment: If you use DFS instead then you can mark nodes as being visited during the recursive call, and unmark them when the call finished.  (Or just use the [all_simple_paths](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/development/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.simple_paths.all_simple_paths.html) function in networkx).

Comment: Is this only for detecting cycles?

Answer (score 0):

When traversing through the graph, instead of marking vertex as visited, try to mark edge as visited.